# Is there a good way of moderating user content without dedicated moderators?

Tags: images, user-generated-content, moderation

I'm building a student project over the summer which is a site that allows users to create a small scoreboard. I want to allow users to upload images to associate with the players. At the moment we're not planning on needing registration to be able to create the scoreboards, the user will just be given two links, one to edit the scoreboard (the private link) and one to view the score (the public link). If the site gets large I could see it becoming very difficult to police certain things such as copyright infringement and illegal content, is there an easy way for me to do this without having to either spend ages trawling through every uploaded image nor a dedicated moderation team?

Comment: This question is considered off-topic because it is board, opionated and slightly off-topic. We do however have a community building beta stack that may be suitable, please see http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/ and read through there rules before posting, to avoid further disappointment.